# Handson Table not saving the cell value

Tags: php, jquery, excel, codeigniter, handsontable

Hi I am using the handsontable for my website admin panel, and also I am using the formulas in some columns. When I am trying to save the handsontable cell values, it saves the formulas but not the value. I want to store the cell value not the formula. Please help me to find out the solution.

Example:

```
[
   {
      "a":"MARKET VALUE",
      "b":"",
      "c":"",
      "d":"",
      "e":"6200000"
   },
   {
      "a":"MUNICIPAL VALUE",
      "b":"",
      "c":"",
      "d":"",
      "e":"3850000"
   },
   {
      "a":"OFFER",
      "b":"=+E3+E4",
      "c":"=E6\/(E3+E4)",
      "d":"=+E6",
      "e":""
   }
]
```

Comment: did you check Budnix answer here: https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/2645?

Comment: @Vickel i am having lot more formula columns. i wand to convert everything while i am saving

Comment: I cant find any solution for this issue i am having 198 arrays, with the formula cells.